# Как правильно использовать word-break:break-all и word-wrap:break-word?

Tags: css, css3, bootstrap

Здравствуйте:

Есть задача, перенести текст внутри элемента.

`word-break:break-all` переносит всё, но коряво:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`word-wrap:break-word` переносит как надо, но только слова, но не переносит одно слово:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, как реализовать чтобы и слово и слова переносились правильно?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Вот](http://htmlbook.ru/blog/perenosy-slov) несколько примеров переноса слов, можете выбрать подходящий:

```css
.block{
  margin: 1rem auto;
  border: 1px solid #555;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 200px;
}
.block-3{
  word-break: break-all;
}
.block-4{
 -moz-hyphens: auto;
 -webkit-hyphens: auto;
 -ms-hyphens: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="block block-1">
Тег <xmp><wbr></xmp>
  Ро<wbr>ня<wbr>ет лес баг<wbr>ря<wbr>ный свой убор,
  Сре<wbr>брит мо<wbr>роз увя<wbr>нув<wbr>шее по<wbr>ле,
  Про<wbr>гля<wbr>нет день как буд<wbr>то по<wbr>не<wbr>во<wbr>ле
  И скро<wbr>ет<wbr>ся за край окруж<wbr>ных гор.
  Пы<wbr>лай, ка<wbr>мин, в моей пус<wbr>тын<wbr>ной келье;
  А ты, вино, осен<wbr>ней сту<wbr>жи друг,
  Про<wbr>лей мне в грудь от<wbr>рад<wbr>ное пох<wbr>мелье,
  Ми<wbr>нут<wbr>ное заб<wbr>венье горь<wbr>ких мук.
</div>
<div class="block block-2">
Мягкий перенос <xmp>&shy;</xmp>
  Ро&shy;ня&shy;ет лес баг&shy;ря&shy;ный свой убор,
  Сре&shy;брит мо&shy;роз увя&shy;нув&shy;шее по&shy;ле,
  Про&shy;гля&shy;нет день как буд&shy;то по&shy;не&shy;во&shy;ле
  И скро&shy;ет&shy;ся за край окруж&shy;ных гор.
  Пы&shy;лай, ка&shy;мин, в моей пус&shy;тын&shy;ной келье;
  А ты, вино, осен&shy;ней сту&shy;жи друг,
  Про&shy;лей мне в грудь от&shy;рад&shy;ное пох&shy;мелье,
  Ми&shy;нут&shy;ное заб&shy;венье горь&shy;ких мук.
</div>
<div class="block block-3">
Свойство <xmp>word-break</xmp>
  Роняет лес багряный свой убор,
  Сребрит мороз увянувшее поле,
  Проглянет день как будто поневоле
  И скроется за край окружных гор.
  Пылай, камин, в моей пустынной келье;
  А ты, вино, осенней стужи друг,
  Пролей мне в грудь отрадное похмелье,
  Минутное забвенье горьких мук.
</div>
<div class="block block-4">
Свойство <xmp>hyphens</xmp>
  Роняет лес багряный свой убор,
  Сребрит мороз увянувшее поле,
  Проглянет день как будто поневоле
  И скроется за край окружных гор.
  Пылай, камин, в моей пустынной келье;
  А ты, вино, осенней стужи друг,
  Пролей мне в грудь отрадное похмелье,
  Минутное забвенье горьких мук.
</div>
```

Comment: Какое из является наиболее кроссбраузерным ?

Comment: `word-break` работает везде кроме оперы, `hyphens` работает почти везде с ошибками, в опере не работает, `<wbr>` работает везде, но его нужно самому проставлять и нет знака переноса, `&shy;` работает везде, но его тоже нужно самому проставлять.